# How do I STOP firebase debugView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I seem to be unable to **stop** my phone from running in debug mode for firebase.

I've run `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.`
but the device still persists on firebase.

In fact it's currently showing that I have **two** devices running (when I only have one) but it should be zero!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out.

From memory this is what i did:

1. Navigate to developer options in the settings menu
2. disabled developer options
3. enable again
4. turn off usb debugging
5. revoke usb debugging authorisations
6. turn on usb debugging

However, it's likely that either:
**disabled developer options** or **revoke usb debugging authorisations** did the trick.